How do I update collections of an XML in MarkLogic that is a very large document?
I'm working with a large XML file in MarkLogic—around 50MB and 700,000 lines long. The task involves adding and removing specific collections using an XQuery module. Previously, I used xdmp:invoke-function() for these operations, but it caused significant performance issues, resulting in timeouts.
After removing the xdmp:invoke-function(), I could manually run the operation in the Query Console, but it still took nearly 8 minutes to complete. Running the same operation as part of a module impacts other modules, leading to system-wide timeouts.
I've tried increasing the transaction time limit to 1 hour and using xdmp:spawn-function() to parallelize the task, but neither approach resolved the issue.
Given that I'm running this on a 3-node cluster, what is the best approach to efficiently update collections for large documents in MarkLogic XQuery?

Adding/removing collections requires an update to that document in MarkLogic. It doesn't matter if you are changing collections or content, it still has to update - and ridiculously large documents (or even reasonably sized documents with a ridiculous number of collections) will take time to save.
It's generally not recommended to manage one large document that's 50MB and 700,000 lines long, but to consider breaking it up into many smaller records. You could always construct such a doc on the way out by combining them in a response if needed.
If you need that document to be one big doc, you might be able to speed up the insert/updates by bypassing some of the indexing and processing that occurs for Text, XML, and JSON docs and save it as a binary-node().

How small would you recommend OP's document to be to achieve substantially better performance?

It's subjective, and largely depends upon what is acceptable for time to process the file (and resources available to do the work, indexing needs, etc.). General guidelines are 1k-100k range for "normal" docs. https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-modeling-guidelines/#:~:text=In%20MarkLogic%2C%20consider%20the%20document,infrastructure%20and%20response%20time%20needs.
